# Odoo KeyError : mail.alias.alias_domain

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

When we open the odoo application we get error like this. The picture of the error is on the link:

[image: KeyError : mail.alias.alias_domain]

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What is being done to generate this error? Is it as soon as you login to Odoo or only when you navigate to a specific screen(s)? If you close the error, can you still navigate through Odoo or does it completely stop you? Do you have any customizations?